# Статус страницы. HTTP заголовки.

Tags: php

Необходимо получить статус страницы и если это 200 (OK), то выполнить действие, в ином случае ничего не делать.

Наработки:

```
    <?php
    $url="http://www.google.co.uk"; 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    $timeout = 5; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $r = curl_exec($ch); 
    var_dump($r); 
    curl_close($ch);
if(проверяем, ответ сервера на код 200) {
выполняем код;
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // return integer type
```

Давно на PHP не писал, инструментария нет чтобы проверить, но должно работать.